# Failing to align badges to right in drop-down bootstrap3 navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Trying to align badges to the right of each drop-down menu. Currently, the badges look like so:

[image: badges, no pull-right]

with the associated code:

```
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown ">
                    <a data-target="/business" href="/business" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Business<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                        <li >
                            <a href="/economy">Economy <span class='badge' today: 2</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li >
                            <a href="/financials">Financial Reports <span class='badge' today: 78</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li >
                            <a href="/interest">Interest Rates </a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
```

adding 'pull-right' to the badge class () causes the badges to collapse:

[image: badges with pull-right]

Also, using boostrap3, with the bootswatch cosmo template (in case that's relevant). Any ideas here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missing closing `>` on the SPAN tags, your class name uses ' not " and your data-target attribute has an invalid leading slash (at least these were what I discovered when I tested it).  The only way I could get it to work was a combination of fixed width for the parent UL, along with right-floated ("pull-right") badge spans.

The following tested successfully in Firefox and Chrome under Twitter-Bootstrap 3:

```
 <li class="dropdown ">
    <a data-target="business" href="/business" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Business<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width:250px;">
        <li>
            <a href="/economy"><span class="badge pull-right">today: 2</span>Economy</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/financials"><span class="badge pull-right">today: 78</span>Financial Reports</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/interest">Interest Rates </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Phil, this worked, but setting the width manually seems very hack-ish. I'm left wondering how this is done in so many other sites..

Comment: Heh heh... yes, it's a tad hackish. Though since you control the content you can make sure the width fits. But the solution is there if you need it.  Do you have examples of any of the "so many other sites" that you mentioned?  That would help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with CSS3 flex boxes:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmsgoo02/4/)

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
        Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li role="presentation">
            <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">
                <span>Something</span>
                <span class="badge">0.5</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
            <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">
                <span>Something else</span>
                <span class="badge">1</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
            <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">
                <span>Something seriously super super long</span>
                <span class="badge">1 bajillion</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
            <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">
                <span>Something also quite long</span>
                <span class="badge">½ bajillion</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu a[role="menuitem"] {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
.dropdown-menu a[role="menuitem"] span:first-child {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    margin-right: 2em;
}
```

Depending on you project you might want to check the [browser compatibility.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes#Browser_compatibility)

[Here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is a good explanation of how it works.

Comment: Good solution.  I had to add align-items: center to get the content of the badges to align correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Since I haven't seen it mentioned in any of the other answers, I wanted to add something:

**There's no need for hacks or fixed-width...**

To move the badge to the right side, keep the *pull-right* but align the Badge with *display:inline-block* and ensure a separation. This will work with any amount of text. Check the demo below.

> Bootstrap 3.3.7

```css
    li a { 
        /*DECORATION*/
        background-color: white; 
    }
    
    .badge { 
        /*DECORATION*/
        background-color: black; 
        color: white;
        
        /*This is important*/
        /*set container in the same line*/
        display: inline-block; 
        /*ensure a constant separation between text and badge*/
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">



<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




    
<div class=" dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
        Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li role="presentation">
            <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" >
                <span>Economy </span>
                <span class="badge rounded-pill pull-right">today: 2</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
            <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">
                <span>Financial Reports </span>
                <span class="badge rounded-pill pull-right">today: 78</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
            <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" >
                <span>Interest Rates</span>
                <span class="badge rounded-pill pull-right">today: 9999999</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

For those in 2020 that are having the same issue with Bootstrap 4, the same solution works.

> Boostrap 4.0.0

http://jsfiddle.net/manyfatboy/bren47ya/7/

Answer (score -1):

Try... (Untested)

```
<li >
    <a href="/economy">
        <span="pull-left">
            Economy
        </span>

        <span class="pull-right">
            <span class='badge' today: 2></span>
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Nope, Gavin, this didn't help.

Comment: It breaks badge to the second line if does not fit into line. Chrome accepts hack of forcing parent width. But FF keeps splitting to two lines.